# How to get thumbnail image for media library all the resources? I have resource id (attachment_id)

Tags: php, image, wordpress, thumbnails

I have attachment id and from that I want to display its thumbnail in case of all type of attachments video,image,audio. So how can i get that? I want the 150X150 px image. wordpress already have this but i dont know how to retrive it. So can any one tell me this?

```
get_attachment_icon($attachment_id);
```

I used this but it is giving image of big size. can any one tell me which funciton of wordpress I should use so that i can directly get the image for all mime types?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are asking, however...

According the the codex get_attachment_icon takes other parameters:
"bool $fullsize Optional, default to false. Whether to have full size image"
and
"array $max_dims Optional. Dimensions of image."

did you try passing those in aswell?

```
get_attachment_icon($attachment_id, false, array(150, 150));
```